# Multiple runbooks get access denied on AzureProfile.json

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

We have set up several runbooks in Azure Automation to backup databases.

We have 4 runbooks, one for each database that we wish to backup.

Each of these runbooks call into a child runbook (DBBackup.ps1), with specific parameters to identify the database to backup, filename prefix for the resultant blob etc.

DBBackup.ps1 has code for selecting the Azure account and the subscription and then performing the backup.

We have a single schedule that runs daily at 1 am, and the 4 database runbooks are linked to this schedule.

This all works fine, sometimes.

What we are ending up with is that because these runbooks are running in parallel, sometimes when they try to set the account and subscription, they are getting the following error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure
>   Powershell\AzureProfile.json' because it is being used by another
>   process. (The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure
>   Powershell\AzureProfile.json' because it is being used by another
>   process.)

I'm not really sure what to do here, as I thought that the runbooks would be isolated as they are running as separate jobs.

Any help appreciated.

**Update from comments:**

I realise that I can wrap this all in retry logic. What I want to understand is why four separate Jobs that I thought would be isolated from each other are trying to access the same local file.

As an example of my overnight results:

[image: Example job list]

The 2nd and 4th jobs in this list fail because AzureProfile.json is locked.

Comment: well, whats the question? this is pretty obvious, implement a retry logic to read the file in each runbook?

Comment: Yes, I could add retry logic around there, but I'm clearly not understanding the isolation of these jobs and would like to.

Comment: it has nothing to do with isolation, you are trying to access a file, no matter how you isolate these jobs they cannot access the same file at the same time if the file is locked...

Comment: So these are all running on the same machine at the same time then?

Comment: our account probably has some nodes assigned to it (in azure somewhere), so when you invoke a runbook (or it starts for any reason, like schedule, webhook, cmdlet, etc) a random node (from the list of nodes) gets chosen and starts executing your runbook, when you queue a second one, it choses a node to run that, it may happen that it would choose the same node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run an Azure Automation runbook on Azure (compared to a hybrid worker), a sandbox environment is generated to run that job. For conservation purposes, jobs run at the same time often end up using the same sandbox environment. In this case, it seems like the AzureProfile.json file is being written to in order to store which subscription you are referencing. Since you are trying to write and change the subscription for each runbook, it is generating a write error. To solve this, I would suggest that you either serialize the runbooks or create multiple Azure Automation accounts to run each one separately at the same time.

---

Edit: ASM cmdlets had a Profile parameter as a built-in workaround, but this isn't supported yet for ARM cmdlets. If this is affecting you, I encourage you to upvote this issue on GitHub (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1257). And in the meanwhile, you can use the below code to potentially lock the sandbox, ensuring that if they land in the same sandbox that the threads are serialized.

```
$LockName = $pid
Write-Verbose "Using lock $lockName";
$Lock = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, $LockName);
$Lock.WaitOne();
try
{

}
finally
{
    $Lock.ReleaseMutex();
    $Lock.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I've done the locking now and haven't had any failures since.